# A mobile web friendly payment gateway?

Tags: mobile, payment-gateway

Can anyone recommend a payment gateway that has been optimised for a mobile?.. I have just checked out paypal on a mobile devise and although it doesn't have a heavy amount of data to be downloaded, it is far from optimised for mobile user experience... i.e. you have to pinch zoom to fill in forms etc... Does anyone know of a payment gateway that is mobile friendly?... Kind regards J

Answer (score 0):

PayPal has a great mobile experience and it will automatically switch to that if using a mobile device.  How do you have PayPal integrated now?  Are you just using a standard button?  How long ago did you create it?

If you take a look at www.givemobiley.org you'll see a good example of PayPal in a mobile experience.  I developed that with jQuery Mobile, and I used the Express Checkout API with PayPal.

If you load the demo on your computer you'll see the experience you expect there, and if you load it on your mobile device you'll see the experience you'd expect there.